# break while loop before negative number

Tags: javascript

Im trying to break a while loop before it goes into the negative numbers but it keeps going past 0 and showing a negative numbers

The problem would be my while loop this is the loop

```
while(Math.round(housetotal)>0){
    housetotal-=o*12;
    zx++;
    row_data.push([zx,
    {v:housetotal, f:'$'+Comma(housetotal)},        
    ]);

    if(zx == year || housetotal<=0){                 
            break
        }

    }
```

my loop works something like this.

lets say

```
housetotal = 239,852 
o = 1,438
```

222,596 and continue to count down to -1,732 after 14 loops

im trying to make it stop at the 13th loop which is 15,524 so it doesn't go into the negative

in my while statement i have if zx which is equal to whatever number i have which in this case is 15 and o*12 is whatever number that comes up multiplied by 12 but in this case is 1,438 x 12 = 17,256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to check the values after the assignment and break the loop then:

```
while(Math.round(housetotal)>0){
   housetotal-=o*12;
   zx++;

   if(zx == year || housetotal<=0)               // moved here
      break;

   row_data.push( [zx, {v:housetotal, f:'$'+Comma(housetotal)}, ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are requiring `housetotal` to be positive after rounding at the very start of each loop iteration, and breaking out of the loop if it's not positive at the very end of each loop iteration. So far, so good.

But then, after those checks, you (1) change the value of `housetotal` and *then* (2) make use of it (in this case, putting it into `row_data`.

If you want to make sure that the value is positive when it's used, you should test it immediately before it's used.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 239.852,
o = 1.432;
while(a>0 && (a-o*12)>0){
    a -= (a-o*12)>0 ? o*12 : 0;
}
```

Comment: I sort of understand what your saying but, I also tried your code as well and it continued to go into the negative.

Comment: But the do your negative value equals to mine?

Comment: What do you mean with "everything repeats" (Sorry, my Ensligh is not very good)

Comment: it returns 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 instead of counting down like 15 14 13 12 11 and so on

Comment: Ok, I'll think a little bit more about it, just gimme some time

Answer (score 0):

Look at the for-loop. It's parts are:

```
<init counter variable>;
while ( <counter condition met> ) {
    <do task>;
    <update counter>;
}
```

When you are updating the counter before doing your repeated task, it will end up with on run where the condition is not met anymore. I'd suggest for your code:

```
while( zx != year && Math.round(housetotal) > 0){
    row_data.push([
        zx,
        {v:housetotal, f:'$'+Comma(housetotal)},        
    ]);

    housetotal-=o*12;
    zx++;
}
```